# How to follow TDD for testing failure on this malloc wrapper?

Tags: c, testing, tdd, malloc

I'm experimenting with TDD and C. I'd like to write a simple malloc wrapper following a TDD approach. I'm trying to follow Bob Martin's Three laws of TDD

1. Do not write production code unless it is to make a failing unit test pass.
2. Do not write more of a unit test than is sufficient to fail, and build failures are failures.
3. Do not write more production code than is sufficient to pass the one failing unit test.

This is my code up until now:

```
    J_STATUS MemAlloc(long Size, void **OutPtr) {
        J_STATUS ReturnStatus;
        void *Ptr;

        Ptr = NULL;

        if (Size >= 0) {
            Ptr = malloc(Size);
            *OutPtr = Ptr;
            ReturnStatus = SUCCESS;
            //TODO controllare malloc error
        } else {
            ReturnStatus = ERROR;
        }
        return ReturnStatus;
    }
```

And these are my tests (I'm using Unity test framework):

```
    #include "../unity/unity.h"
    #include "../src/jMem.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"

    static int *ptr;
    static J_STATUS Result;
    static long Size;
    static long Count;

    void setUp() {
        ptr = NULL;
        Size = 10;
        Count = 5;
    }

    void tearDown() {
        if (ptr != NULL) {
            free(ptr);
        }
    }

    void test_MemAllocShouldAllocateMemoryAndReturnSuccess(void) {
        Result = MemAlloc(Size, (void **) &ptr);
        TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(SUCCESS, Result);
        TEST_ASSERT_NOT_NULL(ptr);

    }

    void test_MemAllocShouldReturnErrorIfSizeIsNegative(void) {
        Size = -4;

        Result = MemAlloc(Size, (void **) &ptr);

        TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(ERROR, Result);
    }
```

Now how do I write a test for a failing malloc? I know I can link a different version of malloc or I could write a macro to make malloc fail, but this should be true only for this test, while in the other I want to use the real malloc.

Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: Introduce a seam for malloc. In c#/java, this is where an interface would come in MemoryManager.Allocate(size). An implementation of MemoryManager if plugged into the calling class. This allows you to swap a compatible implementation that you can control to mimic allocation failure.. e.g. raise OutOfMemoryException in MockMemoryManager. In C, i think a way to get this done would be to use a function pointer instead of an Interface. Same concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To substitute `malloc()` you can use a function pointer like this:

```
void* (*pMalloc)(size_t size)
```

And then you use `pMalloc(some size)` instead of `malloc(some size)`.

If you set the pointer to point at `malloc()`, as in `pMalloc = &malloc;`, you'll be using the real `malloc()`. If you set it to point at your own function, you'll be using that function of yours.

In your function you can simulate a `malloc()` failure by returning `NULL`. You can also call `malloc()` from it, if so is needed for the test.

Similarly you can substitute your own `free()`.

In these substituted functions you can log what's happening.

For example, if you pass `LONG_MAX` to your wrapper function (I'm assuming it still takes the size as a `long` argument), your fake `malloc()` can log the size it has actually received. In the test you can then note that `LONG_MAX` has propagated from the wrapper to `malloc()` as `(size_t)LONG_MAX`, and if `size_t` is shorter than `long` (in terms of the number of bits) you can detect the discrepancy by comparing the values (`LONG_MAX != (size_t)LONG_MAX`).

You can also log the pointer value that your fake `malloc()` returns (from inside of itself) and compare it with the value returned by your wrapper and see if these are different.

You can elaborate the idea further to come up with more tests (e.g. the wrapper returns a non-NULL value, but the fake `malloc()` (and therefore the real one) isn't called at all).

While doing all this you don't have to log to a file or to `stdout`. You can dedicate a data structure for the purpose and then examine it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's an edge case you don't need to test. Just write the code. :-)

On the other hand, since we all like to practice good TDD, another option would be to elevate your malloc call to a function parameter. As a function pointer, you can pass the address of the regular `malloc` in one test and the address of `malloc_that_errors` in the error test case.

Note that it dirties up the interface of your wrapper, which I personally don't like. It breaks the abstraction you're going for and I'd hate to pass `malloc` in everywhere. Given that, I'd go back to not testing it. :-D

Hope that helps!

Brandon

Answer (score 0):

Your malloc wrapper isn't very convincing when it uses `long` rather than `size_t` for the size argument.

You should be able to make it fail by allocating a Very Large amount of memory, use `size_t` and find the maximum value. Most real `malloc()`s won't succeed in allocating that, and so they will fail.

This is, of course, still a rather fake way of getting it to fail, I guess the only proper one is to provide hooks so you can substitute a different `malloc()`.

Comment: Thank you. I read about the use of `long` instead of `size_t` in D. Hanson's book "C Interfaces and Implementation" (from which my wrapper is inspired). I'll try to pass malloc a large size and test that.

Comment: It doesn't work: allocating a large amount of memory doesn't make malloc fail.

Comment: For future Googlers, I came here because I was just doing exactly this: throw overlarge amounts of memory at a `malloc` wrapper to make it fail. The result *was* failure, but not what I expected. My error-handling code never ran because the raw `malloc` failed with an error from `mmap` first. So this approach doesn't work. Probably better to mock out the result of `malloc` as @AlexeyFrunze says.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I feel that, depending on your compiler, there is one answer missing.
GNU LD has a `--wrap symbol` option that lets you override certain functions at link time.

```
void *
__wrap_malloc (int c)
{
  printf ("malloc called with %ld\n", c);
  return __real_malloc (c);
}
```

As with this code every call to `malloc` will be replaced with a call to `__wrap_malloc` and if you would like to call the real malloc it is available through `__real_malloc`.

This functionality might be available with other linkers aswell I don't know, but for GCC it's a nice alternative.